# Cake PHP database check

Tags: javascript, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I was trying to figure out how to check if the value entered in text box is existing in 
database or no as soon as it is entered or on tab event using cakePHP and javascripts. I am new so please can someone help?
Thanks,

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/instatutorial/2011/08/14/check_username_availability_in_cakephp_using_jquery

Comment: Yaa something like this. What I want is when I enter text in text box the text entered should be checked with the value of a particular column in database and if that value exists then just echo that value is present.
The link you provided seems to be useful let me try it and will let you know if it works.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create a validation for Unique on the field. It will check the value of the field before it saves it. If it exists, it will tell the user that the value already exists.

Comment: that's what I don't want it to be unique. So even if the value exists the user should be able to add stuff but he should be notified that the value is present.

Comment: I don't understand. What happens if the value already exists and you warn the user. Can they still add the value again?

Comment: Yes they should be able to add. even if the value exists. It's just that it will inform them that value is existing.

Answer (score 0):

assumptions:
table: posts
model:Post
controller:Posts
and the field about which you need notification of pre-existence is **post_title**

Now do something like this

In view:

let id of text field for post_title is PostPostTitle

```
$('#PostPostTitle').bind({
    blur:function(){
        var newTitle = $(this).val();
        if(newTitle){
            $.ajax({
               url:'Posts/checkTitle/',
               type:'POST',
               data:{title:newValue},
               dataType:'JSON',
               success:function(data){
                    if(data.ok==1){
                       //dont show any error and let the user submit
                    }else {
                       //show error notification in desired format
                    }
               }
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Now in your controller make an action with name checkTitle

controller code will be like this

```
public function checkTitle(){
   //fetch the vlaue of title from appropriate key of the controller class
   //variable $this->params (in cake v<2) or from $this->reuest (cake v2.x+)
   $this->layout = 'ajax';//or json or null what ever you prefer
   $this->autoRender = false;
   //assumig that you have fetched value of newTitle in $newTitle from requestVar
   //make a database query to post table
   $response = array('ok'=>0);
   $data = $this->Post->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('post_title'=>$newTitle)));
   if($data==0) {
      $response['ok']=1;
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
   exit;


}
```